# How to design Bigtable Key

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I would create my optimal key in Bigtable. I know the key design is crucial for query speed and optimization. My case is related to a time series information from a network machine. It is a tall and narrow table with 3 columns: `id`, `info` and `datetime`.

My most frequent query is to get all info for each id for each day.

How should the key be designed to obtain the best performances?
`id#date`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Disclosure: I lead product management for Google Cloud Bigtable.*

> My case is related to a time series information from a network machine. it is a tall and narrow table with 3 columns: id, info and datetime.

Given that the id is in the row key, I am not sure if you need a separate `id` column.

Similarly, can you please clarify why you need to have `datetime` as a separate column? Note that each value in Cloud Bigtable has an associated timestamp, so you don't need to store a separate date/time in a separate column.

> My most frequent query is to get all info for each id for each day.
>
> How should the key be designed to obtain the best performances? id#date?

My recommendation would be to do as you suggested: `id#date` as the row key, and store all the data for that date within a single row, using the timestamp of each cell value to differentiate it, so that you can get the exact timestamp of each reading.

As per above, I think you can drop both the `id` and `datetime` columns, and accomplish this use case with just a single column for the table.

Best of luck with your project; please let us know how it goes!

Comment: Let's say, I have used `id#date` as the row key. And `hoursWorked` as another only column. I could easily get "Number of hours worked on a particular day". How can I meet future requirements like "Number of hrs worked over last 7 days/30 days/ lifetime" and keeping latencies & performances in-check? Any recommendations on implementing these kinda scenarios would be appreciated.

Comment: @tezz – You're asking a different question than the one I answered; please create a new question. Comments are for clarification of existing answer, not for follow-up / additional questions or conversation. You can refer to this question or answer with a link from your question for context if needed. Thanks and all the best!

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex topic that depends on the amount of data you expect to receive, the structure of the ids, the number of ids, etc.

The Cloud Bigtable documentation has a page covering this at length:

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series

which is probably better than can be provided here.

> How should the key be designed to obtain the best performances? id#date?

Assuming you have a lot of machines, and their ids are reasonably different (so they do not hot spot), then maybe id#date#time.  You can query for a id and date using a range, which should be very efficient.